# How to find the max values from columns

Tags: awk

I am trying to find the maxima in three columns of a file called data.dat. The idea is

```
5414 6267 3157 
4521 1235 5418
1366 6472 4598
5153 7814 5648
```

```
5414
7814
5648
```

I'm trying to use `awk` as

```
for k in {1..3};awk 'BEGIN {max = 0} {if ('$k'>max) max='$k'} END {print max}' data.dat;done
```

but I have not been lucky.

Comment: Oh.... Oh... Don't call `awk` in a loop. `awk` is more than capable of handling it all and will be orders of magnitude faster. In a loop you spawn a separate process on every iteration.

Comment: I'm not too skilled using awk, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    arr[i]=(arr[i]>$i?arr[i]:$i)
  }
}
END{
  for(k=1;k<=NF;k++){
    print arr[k]
  }
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                    ##Start a for loop from 1st field to last field of current line.
    arr[i]=(arr[i]>$i?arr[i]:$i)         ##Creating array arr with index of column number and keeping only greater value by comparing its [revious value in each iteration.
  }
}
END{                                     ##Starting END block of this awk program from here.
  for(k=1;k<=NF;k++){                    ##Starting a loop from k=1 to till number of fields here.
    print arr[k]                         ##Printing value of arr with index of k here.
  }
}' Input_file                            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what `awk` arrays are made for. You can simply loop over each field, using the field number as the array index and comparing the value against the current field value. If it is greater, update the value at that index with the current value, e.g.

```
awk '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i > a[i])
            a[i] = $i
}
END {
    for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
        print a[j]
}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

For example, with your data in the filename `file`, you can just open an xterm and select-copy the `awk` script above and middle-mouse paste in the current directory containing `file` to test, e.g.

```
$ awk '{
>     for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
>         if ($i > a[i])
>             a[i] = $i
> }
> END {
>     for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
>         print a[j]
> }' file
5414
7814
5648
```